# Counting the number of orbits for the group action

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

I have have to find the number of orbits for the group action given by the set of all real $2\times 2$ invertible matrices acting on $\mathbb{R^2}$ by matrix multiplication.

I know that if a group $G$ acts on a set $X$ then for each $x\in X$, 
$orbit(x) = \{gx: g\in G\}$, where $g$ runs over all the elements of the group $G$.

Thus here for any $x\in \mathbb{R^2}$ its orbit is given by set $\{Ax : A \in G\}$ and I have to keep in mind that orbits partition the set $X = \mathbb{R^2} $.

**My confusion:** 
Here both group $G$ and set $X$ are of infinite order. So, how to find orbit of all the infinite elements of $\mathbb{R^2}$. Do I have to look at the basis elements of $\mathbb{R^2}$?

I am learning to find the orbits of a set. Any help and basic idea to solve such kind of problem would be very helpful to me.

Thank you very much for your kind consideration.

Comment: Hint: prove that if $\;x,y\in\Bbb R\;,\;\;x,y\neq0\;$ then there exists $\;A\in GL(n,\Bbb R)\;\;s.t.\;\;Ax=y\;$

Comment: @DonAntonio Thanks for you comment. I don't get your point. Could you explain little more?

Comment: this is basic (=not necessarily elementary but *important*) linear algebra: (1) every linear transformation (and thus any matrix) is uniquely and completely determined by its action on any basis of the vector space in question, and (2) A square matrix is regular iff it maps a basis to a basis. Now, remember that $\;x\neq 0\implies x\;$ is part of a basis, so there you go...

Comment: It means there are only two orbits: any non-zero vector $x\in\mathbb R^2$ can be mapped to any other non-zero vector $y\in\mathbb R^2$ by some matrix $A\in G$, so they are in the same orbit, and the zero vector occupies its own orbit.

Answer (score 1):

Take a point $p = (a,b) \in \mathbb{R}^2$. The claim is that taking any point $q =(x,y)\in\mathbb{R}^2$, we find a linear transformation (i.e. matrix) $A$ such that $A p^T = q^T$ (1).

Denote $A = \begin{pmatrix} \alpha & \beta \\ \gamma & \delta \end{pmatrix}$. The equation (1) corresponds to the system $\alpha a + \beta b = x  \,\& \, \gamma a + \delta b = y$, which has in general infinitely many solutions; adding the condition of regularity of $A$, i.e. the zero determinant, will cancel some of them.